# Manually HTTP kerberos authentication

Tags: .net, authentication, kerberos

All the explanations I have found on Kerberos authentication are very high level and conceptual. And all questions here or on other sites have all ended with "Configure like this and it just works" or similar.

So how would I go about implementing Kerberos authentication without ASP/WCF/WebClient/whatever doing it for me. As in, I have a TCPClient and have built an HTTP request.

Are there .NET classes for this (I've messed around with the old WSE 3.0 but it doesn't seem to quite do it)? Are there native WinAPI calls? Or would this require reading the spec and going full on TCP to manually query the KDC? (Or hacking away at the HttpClient source to see how it does it)

Note: This is not about best practices or even an actual use case. This is simply curiosity/educational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The native support comes from SSPI,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Support_Provider_Interface

So if you want to learn the details, dive into the linked resources. Most .NET classes in BCL simply call into such WinAPI.